# Gdb run creating a hanging thread

Tags: macos, gdb

I'm trying to use gdb version 9.2 to debug a C++ file on Mac OS 10.15.
The file I'm debugging is simply a cout statement in the main method.

Within gdb, when I try and 'run' a file, I get something like: [New Thread 0x2741 of process 24251] instead of the actual output or step by step, as the program proceeds to just hang there.

A seemingly unrelated error that might be causing this is that when loading a file the error "unknown command 0x34" appears several times but gdb can still run.

I've seen several other posts about this error, but no actual answers.

I have setup the code cert for gdb.

Also, I can't avoid this issue by not using gdb.

Answer (score 1):

run `gdb` with `sudo` works for me

Answer (score 0):

So here is the solution I found:

run `brew uninstall --force gdb`

This is so you avoid issues from things you tried before.

Then follow the instructions from the next link, ignoring the part about getting the right source, brew now selects a working version at the moment. I am unsure about the gcc stuff, I didn't do that section either.

https://timnash.co.uk/getting-gdb-to-semi-reliably-work-on-mojave-macos/

It should work on MacOS 10.15.

Basically, your output will appear sometimes, and the thread will wait other times.